# Trying to use dynamic fields in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

In themeleaf tutorial they teach you how to extract values from a list using two levels of variables, like this `[[${variable1[__${variable2}__]}]]` but the point is that i want to extract the value using: **`[[${variable1[${variable2[__${variable3}__]}]}]]`** but I don't know how to type this code correctly.

I am trying to create a  HTML element using objects that the Spring server is giving with `mModelAndView.addObject("project",Projects.findById(pid));` and `mModelAndView.addObject("local",posto);`  where Projects and posto are java classes with different variables.

So, if I write this peace of code, all is fine and correct :

HTML & Thymeleaf Code in the page.html:

> ```
> <div th:each="parametro,row1  : ${project.Lista}">
>                                 <p class="info">[[${parametro.pergunta}]]: [[${parametro.rrespostas[0]}]], [[${local.lista_respostas[__${row1.index}__]}]]   </p>
> </div>
> ```

So, all the variables are well understood by themeleaf and this is the result:

[image: code result]

But the point is that i want that the `[[${local.lista_respostas[__${row1.index}__]}]]` variable will be the `[[${parametro.rrespostas[0]}]]` index (the `rrespostas` variable contains a number), that means that I want to substitute this '0' with the `rrespostas` value.

I tried with :

> ```
>  <p class="info">[[${parametro.pergunta}]]: [[${parametro.rrespostas[__${local.lista_respostas[__${row1.index}__]}__}]]   </p>
> <p class="info">[[${parametro.pergunta}]]: [[${parametro.rrespostas[[[${local.lista_respostas[__${row1.index}__]}]]]}]]   </p>
> ```

And i tried more combinations trying to extract the information but nothing works.

Any idea to do that in themeleaf?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you can make this work.

This does not directly fix your problem but:
In my opinion the only clean way is to start using Processors. It is not very hard to write your own and you have the huge benefit of being back in Java-Land where the compiler helps you and you can access all your libraries etc.

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/extendingthymeleaf.html